# Creating chart data from a list of lists ( with start/stop date)

Tags: python, date, range

I'm trying to take a list of dates and numbers in a list of lists, pulled from a spreadsheet, and create a list of dictionaries where each entry is a start date, stop date, and value. The sample data looks like this:

```
d = [[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 0, 0), 50L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 0, 0), 50L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 0, 0), 50L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 0, 0), 23L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 0, 0), 23L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 0, 0), 23L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 7, 0, 0), 23L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 8, 0, 0), 23L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 9, 0, 0), 23L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 9, 0, 0), 23L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 9, 0, 0), 66L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 9, 0, 0), 66L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 13, 0, 0), 50L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 14, 0, 0), 50L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 15, 0, 0), 100L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 16, 0, 0), 100L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 0, 0), 100L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 0, 0), 100L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 0, 0), 100L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 20, 0, 0), 100L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 21, 0, 0), 100L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 21, 0, 0), 100L],
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 23, 0, 0), 50L]]
```

What I need (for later conversion to a Gantt Chart) is output like this:

```
{'start': '11/01/2016', 'end': '11/02/2016', 'IP': '50'}
{'start': '11/02/2016', 'end': '11/09/2016', 'IP': '23'}
{'start': '11/09/2016', 'end': '11/09/2016', 'IP': '66'}
{'start': '11/13/2016', 'end': '11/14/2016', 'IP': '50'}
{'start': '11/15/2016', 'end': '11/21/2016', 'IP': '100'}
{'start': '11/23/2016', 'end': '11/24/2016', 'IP': '50'}
```

I'm getting close, but I can't figure out how to include the last value (yes, they are IP addresses, shortened in my test set for readability).  My current code also messes up the dates on the last to items.

And here is what I'm getting:

```
{'start': '11/01/2016', 'end': '11/02/2016', 'IP': '50'}
{'start': '11/02/2016', 'end': '11/09/2016', 'IP': '23'}
{'start': '11/09/2016', 'end': '11/09/2016', 'IP': '66'}
{'start': '11/14/2016', 'end': '11/14/2016', 'IP': '50'}
{'start': '11/16/2016', 'end': '11/21/2016', 'IP': '100'}
```

Here's my code so far:

```
df = []
fmtD = '%m/%d/%Y'
dates = []
lastIP = 0

for x in range(len(d)):
        ipAdd = d[x][1]
        if ipAdd == lastIP or x == 0:
                dates.append(d[x][0])
        elif ipAdd != lastIP:
                df.append(dict(IP = str(lastIP),\
                               start=min(dates).strftime(fmtD),\
                               end = max(dates).strftime(fmtD)))
                dates = []
        elif x == len(d):
                df.append(dict(IP = str(lastIP),\
                               start=min(dates).strftime(fmtD),\
                               end = max(dates).strftime(fmtD)))
        lastIP = ipAdd 

for item in df:
        print item
```

Comment: What output you are getting? Show that so that we can understand what you are expecting and what you are getting!!

Comment: Thanks.  Added the current output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will never reach last `elif` condition, `elif x == len(d) - 1:` because previously you checked both `ipAdd == lastIP` and `ipAdd != lastIP` in `if ipAdd == lastIP or x == 0:` and `elif ipAdd != lastIP:` condition. So, i guess you have added the last `elif` condition to add the last item of the list to `df`. So, it should be placed outside the for loop. Moreover, after resetting the `dates` list inside `elif ipAdd != lastIP:` condition, you didn't store the current value of the date! Adding a statement, `dates.append(d[x][0])` solves your problem.

Overall, you can modify your code in the following way to achieve your desired output.

```
for x in range(len(d)):
    ipAdd = d[x][1]
    if ipAdd == lastIP or x == 0:
        dates.append(d[x][0])
    elif ipAdd != lastIP:
        df.append(dict(IP = str(lastIP),\
                       start=min(dates).strftime(fmtD),\
                       end = max(dates).strftime(fmtD)))
        dates = []
        dates.append(d[x][0]) 
    lastIP = ipAdd

if x == len(d) - 1:
    df.append(dict(IP = str(lastIP),\
                   start=min(dates).strftime(fmtD),\
                   end = max(dates).strftime(fmtD)))
for item in df:
    print item
```

It will print: (as you expected)

```
{'start': '11/01/2016', 'end': '11/02/2016', 'IP': '50'}
{'start': '11/02/2016', 'end': '11/09/2016', 'IP': '23'}
{'start': '11/09/2016', 'end': '11/09/2016', 'IP': '66'}
{'start': '11/13/2016', 'end': '11/14/2016', 'IP': '50'}
{'start': '11/15/2016', 'end': '11/21/2016', 'IP': '100'}
{'start': '11/23/2016', 'end': '11/23/2016', 'IP': '50'}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I never realized (or even thought to try) testing loop variable outside the loop (x).  It fixes the problem of the last item, but I still get incorrect output.  The second value of 50 should have a start date of 11/13, not 11/14.  I thought that was a related problem, but I guess not.

Comment: @bgrundy now i have understood your problem. I have updated the code and now its giving the desired output. If it helps you, then accept the answer :)

Comment: Yes, that did it.  Second error was from appending the date *after* incrementing x.  So simple.  Thanks.